# How to create a (Azure CLI) command line application in Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, command-line-interface, azure-cli

How to a create command line (CLI) project. I like to add Azure CLI commands to end users in my Angular project. Presently I am tyring to do using C#. So please help me how to do CLI in Angular or C# to integrate my Azure CLI commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run Azure CLI in C# like this:

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText = "/C az login";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

**/C**: Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Angular cannot directly run the CLI commands as this would be a security flaw in the browser.

If you were to acquire a user token from an app registration, you could call Microsoft Graph APIs on behalf of a user. Very detailed explanation on how to do this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular

The other option is to call a C# Web API and run Microsoft Graph or the Azure CLI from the web server. Microsoft Graph SDK is the preferred mechanism from C#, but you could also use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to launch and run Azure CLI commands.